# Import ical into meetup.com?

Tags: meetup

I know that meetup.com can export group events in iCal format, but can it import them from iCal format, or do I (a paying subscriber) have to use either the meetup.com API or web interface to create new events (and/or update existing events)?

Answer (score -1):

Their site says ICal is supported

http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/feeds/

Not sure if that helps

Comment: All the information there is about consuming Meetup.com information in other apps, not the other way around.